# Error installing Expo-CLI .. Even tried npm install --unsafe-perm -g expo-cli but didn't worked

Tags: installation, expo

[This is the error i got when installing the Expo-Cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLcGE.png)

Comment: This can have several reasons:

1) Have you tried using the command line with admin rights?

2) or Clear the NPM cache: rd /s /q C:\Users\stita\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
rd /s /q C:\Users\stita\AppData\Roaming\npm

3) or uninstall all npm modules and re-install with npm install --no-bin-links.

Comment: 4) read here for more possible reasons: 4) Read here for other reasons: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2464